# How do I render pixel by pixel drawing without gaps? Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, pixel

In Java I'm using `JFrame` to plot some fractals, pixel by pixel, but `drawLine` takes `int` arguments and there are pixels I can't reach.  For example, if I draw a line as:

```
g.drawLine(0,100,500,100);
```

then it draws a solid line.  If I draw it as a series of pixels:

```
for (int i=0; i<500;i++) g.drawLine(i,100,i,100);
```

then it draws a dashed line: two pixels, skip one, two pixels, skip one,
etc.

How do I fix it so that my fractal lace doesn't look like I'm looking at it through a screen door? (4/9 pixels filled in).

I'd really like the frame to drop the 1.5x scaling and just plot integers like I was led to believe it would, but I'd also take some other solution up to and including a new graphics package or even learning a new language with better graphics control.

Java version that was the latest version when I downloaded it last month, running via command line on a Windows 10 computer.

Example output so you can see the 'screen door':
[image: RecursiveMobiusMapping]

Minimal working example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example extends JPanel{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
                g.drawLine(i,j,i,j);
    }
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {  

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Inversion");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new Example());
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setLocation(350, 25);
        f.setVisible(true);
 
     }
}
```

output:[image: ScreenDoor]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For better help sooner post a proper [mre] of your code, that shows your best attempt to solve your issue. Post an image of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was creating a"minimal" example.  Added now.

Comment: Don't know if it will help but. 1) custom painting should  be done by overriding `paintComponent()` 2) invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first statement to make sure the background is cleared. 3) The code works fine for me. I see a solid black square. I use JDK11 on Windows 10. Could be an OS issue?

Comment: The second image I posted should look like a solid square, 100 pixels by 100 pixels, but the frame seems to have scaled by 1.5 and I get a 150 by 150 pixel square with 4/9ths of the pixels filled in.

Comment: *but the frame seems to have scaled by 1.5* I was not looking using scaling on my system. When I change to scaling I do see the same problem. Answer below was going to be my suggestion.

Comment: How do you change scaling??

Comment: Note that the issue only arises if your screen uses a scaling factor that isn't a multiple of 100%

Comment: @Andrea scaling is controlled by the operating system.

Comment: That is a Windows property. You go to your desktop and right click. In the popup menu you select "Display Setting". Then look for "Scale and Layout". Generally you want to keep  the recommended setting for best viewing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise against using `Graphics#drawLine` for pixel perfect painting. The coordinated you give are interpreted to be at the top left corner of the "pixel" you are targeting (Pixel in quotes because due to ui scaling a single pixel in gui space could actually be a 2x2 grid of screen pixels or more).

With a stroke width of `1` the line you are drawing will be "between" two pixels, assuming that you are drawing horizontal or vertical lines. This will produce a different outcome depending on screen resolutions and anti-aliasing settings.

Instead use `Graphics#fillRect` e.g. instead of

```java
g.drawLine(x1, y, x2, y);
```

use:

```java
g.fillRect(x1, y, x2 - x1, 1);
```

To draw a single pixel

```java
g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
```

is definitely the incorrect approach. To the `Graphics` object this looks like a line that has no length. If it actually draws it is fully dependent on the implementation at may be inconsistent across platform/screen/etc.
Instead draw a rectangle that has `width` and `height` of `1`:

```java
g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```